# How to set background color below border line using Apexchart React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts

I am trying to set background color below the border line only. Currently it's working the whole line area. I am trying to achieve the background color like the below image,

Here is my try and the code sandbox links:

https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-villani-n164mn?file=/src/App.js

[image]

Comment: This is the [fill](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/fill/) option, not background.

Comment: You can use an Area Chart

Comment: Btw if you want to hide toolbar, grid, legend, labels, etc use [sparkline](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/chart/sparkline/) option in chart ([examples](https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/sparklines/basic/))

Comment: Thanks all for your time and help

Answer (score 1):

Change color of `fill` to same you have in `stroke`

```
fill: {
  colors: ["#98C13C"]
},
```